# Clone/Copy JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, copy

If I have a jqgrid that is properly initialized, and has elements/data.  Is there a way for me to clone/copy the entire thing into a variable and then append it to another html element.

For instance.

```
<table id="ratioTable" class="d" ></table>
```

After the table has been initialized and data put into it... call a function in JS that does something like this.

```
m_Settings.reportElements.push($('#primaryCurrentInjectTable').jqGrid('getGridParam'));
```

Then in another function do something like this..

```
function setReportElements(){
    var report = $('#reportDiv');
    var reportElements = m_Settings.reportElements;
    for(var ix = 0; ix < reportElements.length; ix++){
        report.append(reportElements[ix]);
    }
}
```

The purpose for this is that I have several tables that I need to copy and put into a report.  I figure the easiest way would just be to copy the entire table, and append it to my report div.  Also this runs locally, so while performance is important I have some leeway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay... figured it out as soon as I posted.  Go figure.

Anyways... add "gbox_" to the beginning of your table id and it selects all elements.. like so.

```
m_Settings.reportElements.push($('#gbox_primaryCurrentInjectTable'));
```